# Is there any way to select a javacard applet without using the select APDU command?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu

I want to blacklist an applet from being selected through certain interfaces. I have blocked the use of the select APDU, but i want to make sure that there are no other ways to select the applet. Are there any APDUs I can send that select an applet as a side effect?

Comment: Anything missing from either one of the answers, Ryan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the applet is marked as the default selected applet, then the applet is automatically selected after an ATR/ATS.
If you block the entire SELECT command on the reader side then your other applets might stop working because you cannot select them anymore either.

If you only block the SELECT command for this given applet by matching the APDU header *and* AID, then you should make sure that:

- INS byte is A4
- P1 is 04 (Select by DF-name)
- The Lc byte and command data matches the AID
- The Lc byte and command data matches any substring prefix of the AID

The last point is called SELECT by partial AID which selects the first applet that matches the substring of the AID (and the next one after that).

---

[Edit]: Rereading the question I'm not sure if you might mean blocking the selection from within the applet. My solution is meant to be used from a PCD point of view.

Comment: leaving comments for negative votes is highly appreciated

Comment: PCD = Proximity Coupling Device

Answer (score 2):

Generally NO, unless the Applet is *default selected*, selection of an Applet is always performed using SELECT by Name (where the name is an Application Identifier or AID). This can be detected using [`Applet#selectingApplet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/Applet.html#selectingApplet()) which should work even if selection takes place through another APDU. After that you can use the static [`APDU.getProtocol()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/APDU.html#getProtocol()) method to filter out the unwanted protocols.

However, **the applet cannot stop being selected** by the platform even when you return a bad status word from within the process method. So really the only meaningful answer to the selection is `SW_NO_ERROR` (that's SW `9000` of course). So the previous solution doesn't get you anywhere.

---

Before the SELECT APDU is handled by the process method, Java Card applets also will receive a call to [`Applet.select()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/Applet.html#select()). However, you cannot yet make a decision about the protocol / media within this call; the static methods in the APDU interface aren't yet available for use. If that was possible then it would be possible to block selection through a specific interface. So this won't get you anywhere either.

---

**In the end it may be more practical to simply call [`APDU.getProtocol()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/APDU.html#getProtocol()) for each and every APDU that you receive.** Then throw an `ISOException` with `SW_CONDITIONS_NOT_SATISFIED` or any similar acceptable status word (ISO/IEC doesn't specify which status words to throw, unfortunately, only which ones exist).

Comment: aYou can fail in the select() method to not be selected. but you cannot determine the difference between contact and contactless within java card.

Comment: @PaulBastian Right! Added that info in the answer, sometimes you forget to mention these kind of things - problem with doing Java Card for too long I suppose.

Comment: Hello @MaartenBodewes. Yes you can call APDU.getProtocol() within the Applet.select() method. It works for me. Maybe this behavior is vendor specific if it doesn't work for you.